# Euler's explicit differential equation solving method demonstration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could someone help me to demonstrate the Euler's method on its explicit form ? Im having a few problems, because  I need to start directly with a second order equation :

$y" (x)=f(t,y(t))$

thanks :)

Comment: What problems exactly? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Haha yes I did ! I wouldn't ask you guys if I hadn't.

I would like to start of form this formula, and find Euler's one.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you mean $y''(t)$? Have you tried writing the equations as a two variable first order ODE?

Comment: Well I have tried this, but the thing is that I don't know how to create the seconde variable, because I only have one in my starting ODE.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint/partial answer*:

The equation tells you that $y''$, which is the rate of change of $y'$, is equal to $f$. So to perform Euler's method, you'll need to keep track of both $y'$ (because it is what you know the rate of change of) and $y$ (because it shows up on the right hand side of the equation).

So you update $y'$ each step by adding its rate of change (given by $f$)  times the step size, using your current approximation for $y$ and $y'$ in the formula for $f$.

And you update $y$ each step by adding its rate of change (given by $y'$) times the step size, using your current approximation for $y'$.